# why is SwiftUI modal view updating parent variable here (code attached)

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

In the code below if I change the value of the TextField and then click "Cancel" (i.e. will not then do a coredata save), after this modal view is hidden the value is changed in the parents UI list?

Is this line effectively passing my ref?  If yes how to change to be effectively by value?

UPDATE:  Actually it appears the code in the Save button is getting call directly after the Code in the cancel button, that is in the case I'm clickon on Cancel.  Not sure why this would be occurring?

Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct GCListsViewEdit: View {
    @Environment (\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State var titleStr : String = ""
    var gcItem : GCList?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Enter Details")) {
                    TextField("List Title", text: self.$titleStr)
                        .onAppear {
                            self.titleStr = self.gcItem?.title ?? ""  // ** HERE **
                        }
                }
                HStack {
                    Button("Cancel") {
                        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Button("Save") {
                        guard !self.titleStr.isEmpty else {
                            return
                        }
                        guard let item = self.gcItem else {
                            return
                        }
                        item.title = self.titleStr
                        GCCoreData.save()
                        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Edit List")
        }
    }
}
```

PARENT - just the body part

```
var body : some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {

            // -- Main List  --
            List() {
                ForEach(gcLists) { gcList in
                    HStack {
                        if self.editMode {
                            Button(action: {}) {
                              Text("\(gcList.title)")
                            }
                            .onTapGesture {
                                self.selectedListViewItem = gcList
                                self.newListItemTitle = gcList.title
                                self.showEditView.toggle()
                            }
                            .sheet(isPresented: self.$showEditView, content: {
                                GCListsViewEdit(gcItem: self.selectedListViewItem!)
                            })
                        } else {
                            NavigationLink(destination: GCTasksView(withGcList: gcList)) {
                                Text("\(gcList.title)")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: self.deleteList)
                .onMove(perform: self.move)

            }
            .environment(\.editMode, editMode ? .constant(.active) : .constant(.inactive))
            .alert(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
                Alert(
                    title: Text(verbatim: "Important Message"),
                    message: Text(self.alertString),
                    dismissButton: Alert.Button.default(Text(verbatim: "Cancel"))
                )
            }
            .navigationBarTitle( Text("Todo Lists") )
            .navigationBarItems(
                trailing: Button(action: {
                    print("Edit" as Any)
                    self.editMode = !self.editMode
                } ) {
                    Text(editMode ? "Done" : "Edit")
                }
            )

            // -- Add List Item ---selectedListViewItem
            Button("Add List") {
                self.newListItemTitle = ""
                self.showAddView.toggle()
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showAddView, content: { GCListsViewAdd() } )

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how you implemented the parent ?

Comment: just added in the body part of the parent - is this enough?

Comment: So your question is when you dismiss the edit view,  "self.selectedListViewItem" will be updated ?

Comment: Yes, when I click cancel

Comment: UPDATE:  Actually it appears the code in the Save button is getting call directly after the Code in the cancel button, that is in the case I'm clickon on Cancel.  Not sure why this would be occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Form` is kind of `List` and `List` has specific handling of standard buttons in a row - it makes active entire row, so when row tapped in any place a button (or buttons) got activated.

In your example even if you tap *in between* Cancel and Save, both action are executed.

There are several possible solutions:

1) use tap gestures (keeping buttons or replacing them with other views, Text, Image, etc.), like

```swift
HStack {
    Button("Cancel") {}
    .onTapGesture {
        print(">> do cancel")
    }
    Spacer()
    Button("Save") {}
    .onTapGesture {
        print(">> do save")
    }
}
```

2) use custom button style, because `List` intercepts only `DefaultButtonStyle` buttons

```
struct CustomButton: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .foregroundColor(configuration.isPressed ? Color.gray : Color.blue)
        }
}

HStack {
    Button("Cancel") {
        print(">> do cancel")
    }.buttonStyle(CustomButton())
    Spacer()
    Button("Save") {
        print(">> do save")
    }.buttonStyle(CustomButton())
}
```

3) move buttons out of `Form` for this screen (eg. in `NavigationBar`)

Comment: excellent thanks - does Form look to certain views to demark a "row" does it?   So a HStack must be demarking one row it seems...